# nav-bar link's color is not working in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change link color on nav-bar but after the changing it seems the same. What is wrong? Why its not working? Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top" id="sideNav">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">
    <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Start Bootstrap</span>
    <span class="d-none d-lg-block">
      <img class="img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="img/profile.jpg" alt="">
    </span>
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#experience">Experience</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#education">Education</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#interests">Interests</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#awards">Awards</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

CSS

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: #BD5D38 !important;
}

,
.nav-link {
  color: #222222 !important;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:active {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#sideNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #sideNav {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 17rem;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #sideNav .navbar-brand {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto auto 0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
  #sideNav .navbar-brand .img-profile {
    max-width: 10rem;
    max-height: 10rem;
    border: 0.5rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
  #sideNav .navbar-collapse {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-grow: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
  #sideNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #sideNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    display: block;
  }
  #sideNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I changed it on the .nav-link  class but it's not working.  While nav-link lass is inside  tag. I don't want to use  tags for defining hover and link colors because on my site other links will have other colors while only nav-links must have this color. That is why I am trying to use nav-link class for it. How can I make it worked?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an unneeded comma after closing `.bg-primary` in your css.  Right now it looks like:

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: #BD5D38 !important; },
```

Remove the comma at the end so it should be:

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: #BD5D38 !important; }
```

I think the comma is messing with the following lines of code.  And the important in your color css is preventing the hover, focus and active states to work.

Here is how the top part of your css should look:

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: #BD5D38 !important; }
.nav-link {
  color: #222222;
}
.nav-link:hover, .nav-link:focus, .nav-link:active {color:#ffffff}
```

Also if you are linking to the new beta version of bootstrap 4 you need to be more specific and add the `.navbar-dark .navbar-nav` so it would look like:

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: #BD5D38 !important; 
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #222222;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, 
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:active {
  color:#ffffff
}
```

Comment: Yes but code for links is this part. 
.nav-link {
  color: #222222 !important;
}

  .nav-link:hover, .nav-link:focus, .nav-link:active {
    color: #ffffff; }

Comment: Did you try it.  The comma above these lines is messing with the  .nav-link { color: #222222 !important; } Also remove the !important from this and your hover state will work

Comment: I added this new code but nothing was changed it shows the same.

Comment: Here it is working https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/84nkrsru/ drag the output window bigger so you can see it.  Make sure you are loading your custom css after the bootstrap css.

Comment: jsfiddle works but on codepen not. That's interesting. However thanks for your solution!

Comment: What version of bootstrap 4 are you linking to is it the alpha or the new beta.  If it is the new beta you need to add the .navbar-dark ,navbar-nav before the .nav link if it is the alpha you will just need the .nav-link.  Here it is working on codepen https://codepen.io/wamosjk/pen/ooORXv